# How to insert an array to mongodb using express.js and just mongoclient

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm learning mean stack and just wanted to try insert data into myphonebook db using just the mongoclient, i don't want to use mongoose for now.

How do i insert an array of objects into mongodb? let's say more than 1 address and mobile numbers. I'm not sure how to use the req.body.address or req.body.number

here's my code inside the mongoclient:

```
router.post('/', (req,res)=>{

        var newEntry = {
            firstname: req.body.firstname,
            lastname: req.body.lastname,
            address:[
                // what's the right code here?
            ],
            mobile_numbers:[
                // what's the right code here
            ]
        }

        db.collection("data").insert(newEntry);
        res.redirect('/');

    });
```

and here's the key and value pairs i want to go inside the ff:

1. just string for the address
2. mobile_numbers array:

   {"number": "1234567", "subscriber": "test"}

i'm using a basic form.

```
<form action="/" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Enter firstname">
    <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Enter lastname">
    <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Enter address">
    <input type="text" name="mobileno" placeholder="Enter mobile no.">
    <input type="text" name="subscriber" placeholder="Enter mobile no.">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: what's the problem with this?

Comment: how do i use the req.body for both address and mobile_numbers array,

Comment: `mobile_numbers: [{number:req.body.mobileno, "subscriber": "test"}]` same way you can do for address also.

Comment: thanks, the key and value pairs for the mobile_numbers have 2 fields, so i'm saving both the number and the subscriber, how to insert them both?

Comment: In your html, I see only one input for the mobile number. So are you asking the used to separate them with commas?

Comment: Can you post the `req.body`, so that we can understand what is the structure and then guide with correct code.

Comment: @ Dushyant Bangal i don't know how to structure the form yet, i wanted to have some kind of button so if the user want's more address or mobile numbers the inputs will add on the bottom, actually the mobile numbers has 2 fields, i forgot to include them.

Answer (score 1):

This will completely depend on how you structure the HTML form and in what structure/format you are sending it to the node js API.

If you are sending them in separate fields, you could directly add them in the query in the following way:

```
    mobile_numbers:[
         {number:req.body.num1,subscriber:req.body.sub1},
         {number:req.body.num2,subscriber:req.body.sub2}
    ]
```

Or if you are sending the data in an array, then you could use a forEach and then create the desired structure and then attach it to the query.

Or you could just send the data in the desired structure from the UI itself and the just attach the object to the query

```
    mobile_numbers: req.body.mobile_numbers
```